# Java Generics Map with values limited by key's type parameter

Tags: java, generics, jackson

How can I declare a map variable using Generics, that has **Class of X as Key**, and the related **Serializer of X as Value**.

as example I want to have a Map that can contains:

K, V

BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalSerializer()

LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer()

Date.class, new DateSerializer()

Serializer example:

```
public class BigDecimalSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(FormatUtils.format(value));
    }

}
```

I tried `Map<Class<?>, ? extends JsonSerializer<?>>`

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CsvWriterConfig {
    
    private final Map<Class<?>, ? extends JsonSerializer<?>> serializers;
    private final char separator;
    
}
```

but adding them to SimpleModule

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
serializers.forEach(module::addSerializer);
```

gives me an error:

```
The type SimpleModule does not define addSerializer(Class<capture#5-of ?>, capture#4-of ? extends JsonSerializer<?>) that is applicable here
```

The SimpleModule addSerializer is:

```
public <T> SimpleModule addSerializer(Class<? extends T> type, JsonSerializer<T> ser)
{
    _checkNotNull(type, "type to register serializer for");
    _checkNotNull(ser, "serializer");
    if (_serializers == null) {
        _serializers = new SimpleSerializers();
    }
    _serializers.addSerializer(type, ser);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's no good solution for it .

one possible approach is to use raw types (and delete generics whatsoever)

another would be to add a method to add serializers to the module, and cast types within the method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> void addSerializers(SimpleModule module) {
        this.serializers.forEach((type, serializer) ->
                module.addSerializer((Class<? extends T>) type, (JsonSerializer<T>) serializer));
    }
```

btw, the code above is taken from [spring-web sources](https://github.com/oyh980707/JavaArchitects/blob/939581d646eba0c43e3c1ceba9ffd31fd5607713/code/spring-framework-5.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L722)

The third approach would be to create a wrapper for a Map with accessors methods, which will ensure that no incorrect type-serializer pairs were added. e.g.:

```
        SerializersWrapper serializersWrapper = new SerializersWrapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        serializersWrapper.getAll().forEach(module::addSerializer);
```

and the wrapper code is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SerializersWrapper {
    private final Map<Class,JsonSerializer> serializers = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void addSerializer(Class<T> type, JsonSerializer<T> serializer) {
        serializers.put(type, serializer);
    }

    public <T> JsonSerializer<T>  getSerializer(Class<T> type){
        return serializers.get(type);
    }

    public <T> Map<Class<T>,JsonSerializer<T>> getAll(){
        return (Map<Class<T>, JsonSerializer<T>>) (Map) Collections.unmodifiableMap(serializers);
    }
}
```